# Where my app was downloaded from (exact location)

Tags: android, location

I'd like to reward (somehow) the places (e.g., malls/gyms) from which my Android app was downloaded more often (the mall that generates me more downloads, the one I will reward). Is there any way to know the places (from IP, lat/long or however) that provides more downloads to my app? I think Google Analytics doesn't allow that (the most accurate location it provides is the city... not enough for me), but maybe I'm missing something, some way to achieve that. Any ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, 'no'. Long answer.. get the ip address, do a hollywood backtrace on that ip address, and get the exact location and address for your swat team to move in and give them the reward

Comment: Thanks, @PierreDuc. However, I do not know how to exactly get the IP address by using Analytics. Any clue?

Comment: IP addresses are privacy sensitive date. Even though it is Google, they will not provide you with such information

Comment: OK, so I'm afraid the answer is that I cannot do what I want to do, and that's all. Thanks a lot, @PierreDuc.